# Why are the "emoji" Unicode symbols not well-contained but sprinkled out all over Unicode?

Tags: unicode, emoji

I've spent insane amounts of time trying to block emojis. Following any existing code on the Internet or Stack Exchange is a recipe for disaster: they **all** leave out numerous symbols, and perhaps not just because of incompetence/ignorance: it seems as if Unicode is constantly getting new "blocks" added to it, year after year.

Why do they not have a well-defined range of blocks/slots dedicated for "emojis", so that one can easily and future-proofely block them?

It truly boggles my mind how they could (apparently) make such a technical decision. I'm currently blocking these entire Unicode ranges:

- Dingbats
- Emoticons
- Miscellaneous Symbols
- Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
- Transport and Map Symbols
- Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
- Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A

Even though one is actually called "Emoticons", that only contains a small fraction of the "emojis". The rest are in those other categories above, and possibly (apparently) in further ones. And it also may be that I have blocked ranges which *also* contain legitimate symbols...

Even with all of those ranges blocked, there are *still* many ones which somehow slip through. Flag symbols (                 ), clocks (⌚️ ⌨️ ️ ⏱ ⏲ ⏰ ⌛️ ⏳), stars (⭐️), etc., all in color. They seem to be some kind of "combined" characters, which I don't understand. I find it utterly impossible to block them. When I try to look them up, some don't even seem to exist.

I strongly suspect that there will come a "Symbols and Pictographs Extended-B" soon, and probably others as well. And then I will have to update my code, instead of just getting to block a single range, once.

Can somebody please explain why they did this?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here as we generally can't answer WHY questions not being affiliated in any way to the committee deciding on Unicode extension. Also it's difficult to see the practical use of your code, others do a positive list of usable characters rather than constantly working on a negative list.

Comment: “Even with all of those ranges blocked, there are still many ones which somehow slip through.” Look back at the history of those symbols and past attempts at using pictograms. It seems like what you are considering to be “emojis” (modern) are simply historic remnants of past attempts to add graphics to character sets. They might look like color characters now, but in the past they weren’t.

Comment: if you think flag emojis are weird then check the code points combining into ‍‍‍‍for example. Why do you need to block emojis? Looks like a silly requirement. If the text is for some official documents like address, names... then just limit to a specific language's alphabet. If you don't want emojis then why don't block many other characters like arrows, box drawing characters... as well?

Answer (score 1):

### The history and development of a unified block of emojis has only been a modern thing.

#### The reality is that pictograms (aka: dingbats) have existed in pre-emoji typesets and systems for decades. When you see things spread all over, you need to assume those are past remnants from earlier character sets.

So if you are looking at certain characters as a emoji nowadays, they might just be remnants of early attempts at pictograms and are now made to be “emjoi-fied” in an effort at backward compatiblity.

When you say this:

> “Why do they not have a well-defined range of blocks/slots dedicated for "emojis", so that one can easily and future-proofely block them?”

You assume they just popped out of nowhere and prior to the use of emojis everything was just was a perfect effort. That is not the case. Many of these pictograms pre-existed in past character sets and — to make things more confusing — many character sets were only common in specific regions and cultures. Thus, nobody was really thinking about a unified block but rather, “Where can we add these characters in our character set to deal with the tech demands of our region/market.”

As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Modern-day_emojis_(2010%E2%80%93present)); bold emphasis is mine:

> “**The popularity of emoji has caused pressure from vendors and international markets to add additional designs into the Unicode standard to meet the demands of different cultures.** Unicode 7.0 added approximately 250 emoji, many from the Webdings and Wingdings fonts. **Some characters now defined as emoji are inherited from a variety of pre-Unicode messenger systems not only used in Japan, including Yahoo and MSN Messenger.** Unicode 8.0 added another 41 emoji, including articles of sports equipment such as the cricket bat, food items such as the taco, signs of the Zodiac, new facial expressions, and symbols for places of worship.”

One historic legacy item in the Western world was [Zapf Dingbats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapf_Dingbats) which was initially developed in 1977 for non-digital print use but saw increased popularity in the computer world in the 1980s and early 1990s when Zapf Dingbats series 100 was widely implemented on PostScript printers.

As for why you see them in color, it is basically past pictograms renders as color in your OS if that OS supports such characters being rendered as full-color emoji.

Your best bet if you want to detect and possible code against what is an emoji or not is to refer to official emoji reference likes provided by the source reference everyone uses: The official Unicode, Inc. [lists found here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/).

Here is a direct link for the most recent [version 13.1](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-sequences.txt) from September 2020 and you can compare and contrast with [version 1.0](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt) from August 2015. Lots have changed and continues to change; to code against emoji means you will be coding against a moving target. That’s sadly the nature of this beast.